# Switch Save user preference

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to send a tag with OneSignal when the switch is turned on, and send request to delete the tag when it is turned off again.

```
@IBAction func tagGeneral(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if (sender.isOn == true) {
        OneSignal.sendTag("General", value: "value")
        print("sendtag")
    }
    else {
      OneSignal.deleteTag("General")
        print("deletetag")
    }
 }
```

This is the code i use for it. Seems to be working but when the user goes to another page the switch is automatically turned off...

How can i fix this?

Comment: Store the state somewhere. IE> UserDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding @Ryan's comment, Here's an answer:

First. there are many ways to save the user preference, i'll be doing it with `UserDefaults()` | Edit your button action code:

```
@IBAction func tagGeneral(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    let userdef = UserDefaults.standard

    if (sender.isOn == true) {
        OneSignal.sendTag("General", value: "value")
        print("sendtag") 

        // user made the choice
        userdef.set(true, forKey: "sw_set")
    } else {
      OneSignal.deleteTag("General")
        print("deletetag")

        // reset 
        userdef.set(false, forKey: "sw_set")
    }
 }
```

Normally this wouldn't work without this little function, make sure you call this function in your `viewDidAppear()`:

```
private func init_switch() {
     // Thanks @Vadian for the tip

    let userdef = UserDefaults.standard
    self.yourSwitch.isOn = userdef.bool(forKey: "sw_set")
}
```

Call it in `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

   self.init_switch()
}
```

And let me know if it helped.

Comment: Why not directly `self.yourSwitch.isOn = userdef.bool(forKey: "sw_set")`?

Comment: Needs to be unwrapped and complicates the code. I'm sorry, If you don't like it i could edit it

Comment: No, there's nothing to be unwrapped. And it simplifies the code.

Comment: Well the bool does not exist in the first place it would either return false or needs a `?`, Thanks for the tip

Comment: *If the bool does not exist* it returns `false`, this method returns always a non-optional.

Comment: Thank youu. Just edited. Will surely keep that in mind

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the help! When i change the yourSwitch.isOn to tagGeneral.isOn i get this error: Value of type '(UISwitch) -> ()' has no member 'isOn'...

Comment: Hey, i fixed it! I had to add an outlet to it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I’m glad it helped :)